# Database design for a S3 based file storage application

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, amazon-s3

I am working on a file storage application and I am using PHP and MySQL as my tools. My use case is user can share **multiple files with multiple users** using the app. The sender will send URLs via email and the receiver has to click on the link and login to see the file. So when a user shares a file I want to make an entry to the database.

```
 id|filename|shared_with|shared_by|shared_on|shared_url|url_expiration
```

Now, the above is my currently thought database structure. But in this case I will have to store multiple multiple values if the **same file is shared with multiple users**, which I believe is not a good way to do. Also, storing comma(,) separated values is not a good idea.

I gave a thought to Document database like Mongo DB (just because dropbox uses it and handles key value pair data well). But as MySQL can handle a decent amount of records and NOSQL can be a potential solution for **bigdata** now, I am not sure which would be the right way to go about this use case.

I would like the experts to throw some light on it. I am using Amazon S3 for storing files.

Comment: Are you familiar with Relational database design patterns? This would be very straightforward in a traditional DB. You shouldn't be using commas as a delimiter.... (you'd create columns).

Comment: @WiredPrairie I did not get your point.If I have 1 file shared with 10 users,the `shared_with` column will have 10 entries against a single entry in the `filename` and `shared_by` column,right?If I understand RDBMS :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very basic design to get you started...

You need a table to store your file information:

```
files
    id              unsigned int(P)
    owner_id        unsigned int(F users.id)
    name            varchar(255)

+----+----------+----------+
| id | owner_id | name     |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |        1 | File A   |
|  2 |        1 | File B   |
|  3 |        1 | File C   |
|  4 |        2 | File 123 |
| .. | ........ | ........ |
+----+----------+----------+
```

You need a table to store information about what files where shared with whom. In my example data you see **bob** shared **File A** with **mary** and **jim**, then he shared **File B** with **mary**.

```
shares
    id              unsigned int(P)
    file_id         unsigned int(F files.id)
    shared_with     unsigned int(F user.id)
    shared          datetime
    url             varchar(255)
    url_expires     datetime

+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+
| id | file_id | shared_with | shared              | url   | url_expires         |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |           2 | 2014-01-06 08:00:00 | <url> | 2014-01-07 08:00:00 |
|  2 |       1 |           3 | 2014-01-06 08:00:00 | <url> | 2014-01-07 08:00:00 |
|  3 |       2 |           2 | 2014-01-06 08:15:32 | <url> | 2014-01-07 08:15:32 |
| .. | ....... | ........... | ................... | ..... | ................... |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+
```

And finally you need a table to store user information.

```
users
    id              unsigned int(P)
    username        varchar(32)
    password        varbinary(255)
    ...

+----+----------+----------+-----+
| id | username | password | ... |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
|  1 | bob      | ******** | ... |
|  2 | mary     | ******** | ... |
|  3 | jim      | ******** | ... |
| .. | ........ | ........ | ... |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you @Benny Hill,I was wondering what would be the right way to index it as it will grow pretty fast since users can send files to multiple people consistently.While I fetch them from the database they have to indexed in a way for best performance.One way I believe can be having clustered records based on owner_id or receiver_id so that they are available in chunks.